# Eclipse tycho updating version to svn revision

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn, tycho

i want to update the minor version number of
`product`, all `feature` and all `modules` to its coresponding `svn revision number` (later only mentioned as `buildNumber`).

this shall work automatically, so no modification on `.product`, `feature.xml`, `MANIFEST.MF` nor `pom.xml` are needed

My RCP Applicatin has the following structure (names simplified)

- parent
- feature-core
- feature-addons(4)
- modules(loads)
- product

i tried to include `buildnumber-maven-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>create</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <doCheck>true</doCheck>
        <doUpdate>true</doUpdate>
        <providerImplementations>
            <svn>javasvn</svn>
        </providerImplementations>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.maven-scm-provider-svnjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-svnjava</artifactId>
            <!-- version>2.1.1</version -->
            <!-- latest is 2.1.1 -->
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</groupId>
            <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
            <!-- version>1.8.11</version -->
            <!-- latest is 1.8.11 -->
            <version>1.7.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

and

```
<finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-r${buildNumber}</finalName>
```

but this only creates a zip file with the `buildNumber` and leaves the version untouched.
`p2 update manager` requires the version to change (a simple `SNAPSHOT` build does not work for my `product`)

so by now the version number is eg. `1.0.0` and should be automatically updated to `1.0.${buildNumber}`

its ok, if this is not possible in the parent pom and needs to be done in each feature or modules pom

Answer (score 0):

there is a feature in Tycho that updates the version qualifier (4th digit) to the timestamp of the latest git commit:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Reproducible_Version_Qualifiers

https://git.eclipse.org/c/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho.extras.git/tree/tycho-buildtimestamp-jgit/src/main/java/org/eclipse/tycho/extras/buildtimestamp/jgit/JGitBuildTimestampProvider.java

you would have to develop a similar BuildTimeStampProvider plexus component for SVN.

Comment: the problem is, that i also need this information in .product, feature.xml and MANIFEST.MF because the p2 updater searches in there for the version number (i found a plugin that would increment version number, but not using svn)

Comment: .qualifier is used as a suffix in versions of MANIFEST.MF, feature.xml and .product files. See example build https://github.com/eclipse/tycho-demo/tree/master/itp04-rcp

Comment: i do know how a .qualifier works. and i do use it already. still this does not bring the revision number from svn to my mf and xml files.